# navigate from one page to another page onclick

Tags: iphone

I would like to know a method for navigating from one page to another page onclick .I 
have tried
[self.navigationController 
     pushViewController:self
     .objectNewlist 
     animated:YES];
but it is showing the error
  Incompatible pointer types sending 'newlistplist *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'

my main class file is a subclass of UIViewController
and the second class is a subclass of UITableViewController
can any one help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"<name of xib>" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
[yourViewController release];
```

In case the new view is also to be created programmatically, you can do that in the viewDidLoad method of YourViewControllerClass and change the initialization to

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] init];
```

In YourViewController when you wish to come back to previous view on some button action you can use

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Another way that you can do is

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc] init];
[self addSubview:[yourViewController view]];
```

and to remove the view you can use

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: thank you for your response.I would like to know one more thing .Is plist a good method for storing the data?

Comment: if u r problem is solved then make it as an answer so that other can refer it....

Comment: addSubview shouldn't be used for UIViewController! better present the views modally

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)onClickButton
 {
   ViewControllerClass *objViewControllerClass = [ViewControllerClass alloc] init] ;
   [self presentModalViewController:objViewControllerClass animated:YES];
   [objViewControllerClass release];
 }
```

objViewControllerClass (object of another class)